# Add prefix in @RequestMapping annotation in Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm working in ***Spring Framework 5*** in **Eclipse** and I need to add a prefix to many of my `@RestControllers`, so I found that placing this: `@RequestMapping("${foo.bar}")` at the beginning of the class and adding a new file `application.properties` to `main/java/resources` will solve my problem.

The content of `application.properties` is:
`foo.bar=/test`

But it doesn't work because when I try to access on my web explorer to: `localhost:8080/project/test` I get a **404 Error**. It works only if I access with `localhost:8080/project/$%7Bfoo.bar%7D`. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong. I don't know if Spring will detect automatically the properties file or not.

Can someone help me?

Comment: could you please try putting your application.properties file in src/main/resources directory

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what the use case of this prefix is? There are some existing tools that might be applicable. Also, you didn't say whether you were using Spring Boot. You really should be with a Spring 5 project, since it's the modern way to develop, but if you aren't, that might explain why your placeholder isn't working.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Sure, I's using **Spring Framework** not Spring Boot BTW. I'm using this prefix to separate two api-rest in the same project: **web-api** and **mobile-api**, so I have a lot of `RestControllers` using `web-api` and a lot of `RestControllers` using `mobile-api`. So the idea is not to write in all clases which back-end are you going to use.

Comment: @ShubhamPathak Sorry, I got confused, yes the file is in: `src/main/resources', but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The values from the properties file are accessed from the spring bean. But the @Restcontroller is used to register the bean that provides the restful service.

And for request mapping the controller, you just have to hardcode the value like this as at this point you can't get the message resource object yet.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
```

Just for the information, to access labels from the properties file inside the controller you have to @Autowired a MessageResource object in the RestController

```
@Autowired
private MessageResource;
```

and access the labels of the properties file like this in any of the controller methods.

```
message = messageResource.getMessage("foo.bar");
```

Comment: The `@RequestMapping` is at the top of the class, so I can't use a variable to provide the value.

Comment: Yes, please mark my answer as correct if this resolved your query. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't help me, You can read the other comments in order to get a best context. thanks :)